# How to interact with proxy contract with ethers and wagmi

Tags: ethers.js, delegatecall, proxy-contracts, wagmi

I have an upgradable proxy contract that points to a specific contract. This is the contract in mumbai polygonscan => https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xbE70d41FB3505385c01429cbcCB1943646Db344f#code

Now, Contract A is proxy contract that points to contract B. I want to call some functions in B contract. I don't know how to.

For instance, I'm using wagmi hooks in my application, and in my contract B there's this "vaults()" function that's a view function, so it shouldn't cost gas. I want to call that vaults function, but in order to reach contract B, I guess I need to go from contract A.

I write this code =>

```
  const { data, isError, isLoading } = useContractRead({
    address: "0xbE70d41FB3505385c01429cbcCB1943646Db344f",
    abi: abi,
    functionName: "vaults",
  });
```

In the above code, the address is the address of contract A, as contract B's address will change in the future. But, since contract A doesn't have the function vaults, this code returns this error => `ntractMethodDoesNotExistError: Function "vaults" on contract "0xbE70d41FB3505385c01429cbcCB1943646Db344f" does not exist.`

In short, how do I call the function "vaults" that's in contract B, from contract A? All help is appreciated.